# Busy indicator not showing up in wpf window

Tags: c#, wpf, busyindicator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [wpf busyindicator not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528438/wpf-busyindicator-not-showing-up)

I am tryihng to use busy indicator in a window like this:

```
   <extToolkit:BusyIndicator Width="160" Height="100"
               x:Name="busyIndicator" Visibility="Hidden"  />
```

I am trying to call this when the user chooses some files to import and then im doing some parsing on those files.

And setting these two properties:

```
importProgressBar.busyIndicator.IsBusy = true;
importProgressBar.busyIndicator.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

before the window pops up.

I am calling a delegate function whenever a file parsing is finished. And inside that I'm calling the window with the busy indicator.

```
private void ShowIndicator(ProgressReport progressReport)
{
    window.Show();

    if (progressReport.OverallProgress.Completed)
    {
        window.Close();
    }
}
```

So as you can see inside this function I have property completed which on complete will close the window automatically but the window shows up with no busy indicator.

Can someone point out why busy indicator is not showing in window?

Comment: what is importProgressBar in importProgressBar.busyIndicator ? I'd expect it to be the Window but judging from the name, its a progressbar?

Comment: Bit of a head scratcher there then. Are you by any chance calling IsBusy=true from a thread different from UI thread? You may be having a cross-thread value manipulation error and you may need to invoke the IsBusy property setting on UI thread

Comment: I m not creating any seperate thread right now.I am just trying to do on worker thread right now.

Comment: I haven't used this control before, but could it be that the z-Order is preventing it from showing (e.g., it is obscured by other controls)? Maybe you can show us the XAML code where you define your importProgresbar.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
new Action(() => { Window.Show() }));
```

Comment: I tried adding busy indicator in the same window as well and it is not showing up.