# wpf busyindicator not showing up

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, busyindicator

I have a wpf busy indicator like this on my window:

```
<Grid><Controls1:BusyIndicator  x:Name="busyIndicator2" IsBusy="False" Content="Please wait....." Visibility="Hidden"/>
</Grid>
```

And in the button click I m trying to set the visiblity,isBusy property of indicator to true and visible.

```
void button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   busyIndicator2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
   busyIndicator2.IsBusy = true;
}
```

but the indicaotr is not showing up.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 6):

I've always wrapped other wpf content with the BusyIndicator, it then shows up centered over that content.

```
<BusyIndicator...>
  <Grid>....</Grid>
</BusyIndicator>
```

Try wrapping your layout control in the BusyIndicator and see if that does what you are after.

Answer (score 2):

Where is the BusyIndicator defined? For example, if your XAML looks like:

```
<Grid>
  <BusyIndicator ...>
  </BusyIndicator>

  <ListBox ...>
  </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

You'll never see the `BusyIndicator` because it's behind the ListBox. I would recommend using the `BusyIndicator` as suggested by Chris, otherwise, make sure it's not inadvertently behind other visuals.

Comment: Yes I have defined just like that.